# Null exception error while navigating

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

In my windows store application , i am passing some parameters between two pages like this:

```
Window.Current.Content = new page2(a1,a2,a3);
```

and accessing that parameters in page2 like this :

```
 public page2(string a1, string a2, string a3)
{this.InitializeComponent();}
```

everything works fine, but when i am trying to navigate from page2 to another page , a null exception is occurring. what is the problem ??

Comment: This is not nearly enough code to find where you might be getting a null ref.  Also, if you look at the stack trace of the exception, it should tell you exactly where the null exception is being thrown...

Comment: null exception is thrown at this line   'this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(page3));' (navigating on button click)

Answer (score 3):

Please check the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790344/argumentnullexception-on-changing-frame). Possible you can follow this solution for resolve your issue.

Or you can try that too:

```
var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
frame.Navigate(typeof(Page3));
```

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the issue by using this kind of navigation `Window.Current.Content = new page2();`
instead of this `this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(page));`

Comment: Do you know why this works ? `this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(page));` this works when you do navigation through a button click or something but why does it not work when called through the Main function ?